# New controller validation error due to no PK on inherited classes ASP.NET MVC VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to add a controller in VS2015, via the RMB > Add > controller... option.  I try and add an MVC controller with views and I receive the following error stating

"*There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'myNamespace.Service'.  One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:*

*ImageService: : EntityType 'ImageService has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.*"

I know this is because each model in EF requires a key but these classes are children of the Image class, therefore should not have a PK of their own as the PK is derrived from the parent as TPH will merge this all into one DB table anyway.

Also, [NotMap] would not be appropriate here as the FK field (and any other fields to be added, will need to be mapped.

My Image class parent code is as below:

```
public abstract class Image
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ImageType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [Required]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; } = false;

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    //*********** Static Public Fields *********
    public static string defaultImgLocation = "/Storage/Global/NoImg.jpg";

    public Image()
    {

    }

    public Image(ImageType type, string imgLocation, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        Location = saveImage(imgLocation, file);
        Type = type;
    }
```

Child class causing the issue:

```
public class ImageService : Image
{
    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    public Service Service { get; set; }

    public ImageService() : base()
    {

    }

    public ImageService(HttpPostedFileBase file, ImageType imgType, string imgLocation, Service svcObj) : base(imgType, imgLocation, file)
    {
        Service = svcObj;
    }
}
```

There are numerous other child classes, some with extra fields in them and some that don't have any extra fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the [Key] data annotation to the ImageID property in the Image class

Comment: Also is TPH set up correctly, e.g. the derived context contains only something like `public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }`?

Comment: Ivan, thank you for your comment.  That's correct the context is set up for TPH

Comment: Sparrow, thank you for your comment.  Turns out you're right!  Do you know why I have to explicitly label the PK with the Key attribute?  My naming convention fits with EF's PK naming convention, therefore EF knows it is a PK and treats it as such, surely VS should know this too?

Comment: Off topic, but maybe important: *numerous other child classes* spells improper use of inheritance. Consider composition (in terms of database schema: further normalization). Another tell-tale is `ImageService` as subclass of `Image`. The names suggest quite different responsibilities.

Comment: Hi Gert, I have 4 child classes of ImageService, ImageUser, ImageProperty, ImageEvent and each child represents an image for an entity in the app.  Eg, ImageProperty for a Property object (eg house), ImageService for an image to advertise services offered. I've done it this way because otherwise I would have an image object with loads of other objects representing the FK and parent object in one large Image class plus i can add specific property fields to different image objects. I can also use OfType<> to find groups of images as required. If there's another way I'm all ears?

Comment: Hehe, four isn't exactly "numerous". And maybe `ServiceImage`, etc. would be better semantically. Oh, and one more thing, I would decouple your DAL from System.Web.